# Fix a Hp pavilion 15 n-267sa

Tags: laptop, reset

I was using an hdmi cable and my t.v to operate this laptop. The coonection to the t.v has stopped working and as the screen is damage i an struggling to troubleshoot.

I am happy to lose my data so any method of resetting the laptop to factory, bypassing the login screen or somehow getting the external monitor to display the screen would be of great help.

I can see enough of the screen to know that i am on the login screen. I have also been able. To bring up HP recovery but I could not seem to select any options. It seems all the reset/recovery tools require clicking on each prompt. I am searching for a way to recover a laptob with a broken screen. I can not connect it to another monitor. I need a method that requires only my keyboard to carry out please help.

Thank you

Comment: the details you've provided are too few to even say whether it's lost or not. Your best option is to bring it to a local technician to check it.

Comment: Sounds pretty bad, did you run over it with a truck?

Comment: Lol nah just dropped it lol

Comment: I fixed it. Took the laptop apart and disconnected the display. Without it's own screen to send images to the HDMI connection now works. So i now have a desktop pc but better that nothing. It seems like a design flaw that the external screen can only be used after the login screen.

Comment: Wild way of  fixing it, well done. Make sure you self answer. Sometimes you can hit windows key + P to switch between different screen modes to get the correct one (you likely want duplicated but accidently switched to 'screen 1 only' which would of just been the laptop screen.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by dismantling the laptop and removing the entire display unit, with no display attatched the laptop's picture now shows on the external screen as soon as it is switched on.
Then I used my recovery usb to restore it to factory setting thus solving the firgotten password problem as well.
This was my first attempt at electronics reoair and I have found a new hobby.